# pt-archiver hangs on last remaining rows

Tags: mysql, freeze, percona

I am trying to purge mysql table with pt-archiver and facing a strange issue.

Suppose following query returns 60789 rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM abc WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2008-09-01 00:00:00' AND '2008-09-05 23:59:59';
```

And i am using following pt-archiver syntax to purge rows.

```
/usr/local/bin/pt-archiver --source h=localhost,u=root,p=abcdef,D=cbs_production,t=abc \
--where "created_at >= '2008-09-01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2008-09-05 23:59:59'" \
--purge --sleep-coef 1.0 --txn-size 1000 --progress=1000 --statistics
```

So it starts deleting rows 1000 in each iteration but when it completes 61000 then it hangs forever and it does not delete remaining 789 rows.

I tried following versions of Percona Toolkit.
pt-archiver 3.0.9 and pt-archiver 3.0.10

I also consulted following posts but nothing works.

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1096274
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1583498
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1193474

Comment: Not really sure what kind of help you are looking for here on SO, since this is a Q/A site for sw developers. You do not have a programming question, you need to figure out why a tool does not do what it is supposed to do. DBA SE site, or percona's own support forum would be lot better candidates for question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue that you are facing:

```
$ pt-archiver --version
pt-archiver 3.0.9
```

Is it possible to send your MySQL version and table structure?

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>\G
SELECT @@version;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Vinicius. I figured out the issue.

I was using --where statement as following.

```
--where "created_at >= '2008-09-01 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2008-09-05 23:59:59'"
```

When i was using "created_at" pt-archiver stuck forever on last transaction. Then i decided to use table,s primary key "id" in --where statement as following.

```
--where "id>=18689121 AND id<=19998441"
```

So with "id" pt-archiver worked flawlessly.

I am not sure why it does not work with timestamps but issue is resolved when "id" is used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how easily one can figure out the PK `id` range to be passed in to the `pt-archiver` script.

A more appropriate solution is to update the `pt-archiver` script as described in this thread: https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-toolkit/+bug/1193474/comments/4